# incremental value of single text box on javascript dynamic table

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dynamically created table with 4 text inputs and 1 drop down selection. 
When the user clicks the Add button, a clone of the previous row is added to the table. That works as it should. what I'm trying to do is increase the Unit ID input by 1. For example first row is 1111T-01 when the add button is clicked I want the next row Unit ID to be 1111T-02. Thank you.

**HTML CODE**

```
<h2>Please fill in the information below</h2>
        <form action="pmUnitCreate.php" method="post">
            <p>Click the Add button to add a new row. Click the Delete button to Delete ALL rows.</p>

            <input type="button" id="btnAdd" class="button-add" onClick="addRow('myTable')" value="Add"/>
             <input type="button" id="btnDelete" class="button-delete" onClick="deleteRow('myTable')" value="Delete"/>



            <br>

            <table id="myTable" class="form">

                 <tr id="heading">
                <th><b><font size="4">Job Number</font></b></th>
                <th><b><font size="4">Job Code</font></b></th>
                <th><b><font size="4">Unit ID</font></b></th>
                <th><b><font size="4">Model Number</font></b></th>
                <th><b><font size="4">Scope</font></b></th>
                </tr>   

                <tr id="tableRow">
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="JobNumber[]" required>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="JobCode[]" required>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="UnitID[]" required>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="ModelNumber[]" required>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <select id="Scope" name="Scope[]" required>
                            <option>100OA</option>
                            <option>BTank</option>
                            <option>WSEcon</option>
                            <option>NetPkg</option>
                            <option>CstmCtrl</option>
                            <option>CstmRef</option>
                            <option>CstmSM</option>
                            <option>CstmHV</option>
                            <option>CPCtrl</option>
                            <option>DesiHW</option>
                            <option>DigScroll</option>
                            <option>DFGas</option>
                            <option>DWall</option>
                            <option>MZ-DD</option>
                            <option>DPP</option>
                            <option>Encl</option>
                            <option>PlateHX</option>
                            <option>ERW</option>
                            <option>ERWModule</option>
                            <option>ERVMod</option>
                            <option>EvapBP</option>
                            <option>PreEvap</option>
                            <option>XP</option>
                            <option>Extend</option>
                            <option>FanWall</option>
                            <option>FillStat</option>
                            <option>FFilt</option>
                            <option>PFilt</option>
                            <option>CarbFilt</option>
                            <option>CustFilt</option>
                            <option>MGH(H)</option>
                            <option>GHeat</option>
                            <option>HighStatic</option>
                            <option>HGBP</option>
                            <option>HGRH</option>
                            <option>HPConv</option>
                            <option>GFHumid</option>
                            <option>TOHumid</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>

                </tr>


            </table>
```

**JS CODE**

```
            <script>

                function addRow() {
                    var row = document.getElementById("tableRow"); // find row to copy
                    var table = document.getElementById("myTable"); // find table to append to
                    var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
                    //clone.id = "newID"; // change id or other attributes/contents
                    table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
                }


               function deleteRow() {
                    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(-1);
                     }

            </script>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8hxoaz3z/)

Comment: Is the unitId always with the `xxxx-01`, `xxxx-02` format?

Comment: Yes the Unit id will always be XXXX-01 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the unit id is always `xxxx-1` and the x is never a `-` this should do the work.

If the `x` can be a `-` let me know and I'll update the answer accordingly.

```js
function incrementUnitId(unitId) {
  var arr = unitId.split('-');
  if (arr.length === 1) {return;} // The unit id is not valid;
  var number = parseInt(arr[1]) + 1;
  return arr[0] + '-' + (number < 10 ? 0 : '') + number;
}

function addRow() {                
  var row = document.getElementById("tableRow"); // find row to copy
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable"); // find table to append to
  var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
  row.id = "oldRow"; // We want to take the last value inserted
  clone.cells[2].childNodes[1].value = incrementUnitId(clone.cells[2].childNodes[1].value)
  table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
}


function deleteRow() {
  document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(-1);
}
```

```html
<h2>Please fill in the information below</h2>
        <form action="pmUnitCreate.php" method="post">
            <p>Click the Add button to add a new row. Click the Delete button to Delete ALL rows.</p>

            <input type="button" id="btnAdd" class="button-add" onClick="addRow('myTable')" value="Add"/>
             <input type="button" id="btnDelete" class="button-delete" onClick="deleteRow('myTable')" value="Delete"/>



            <br>

            <table id="myTable" class="form">

                 <tr id="heading">
                <th><b><font size="4">Job Number</font></b></th>
                <th><b><font size="4">Job Code</font></b></th>
                <th><b><font size="4">Unit ID</font></b></th>
                <th><b><font size="4">Model Number</font></b></th>
                <th><b><font size="4">Scope</font></b></th>
                </tr>   

                <tr id="tableRow">
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="JobNumber[]" required>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="JobCode[]" required>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="UnitID[]" required>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="ModelNumber[]" required>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <select id="Scope" name="Scope[]" required>
                            <option>100OA</option>
                            <option>BTank</option>
                            <option>WSEcon</option>
                            <option>NetPkg</option>
                            <option>CstmCtrl</option>
                            <option>CstmRef</option>
                            <option>CstmSM</option>
                            <option>CstmHV</option>
                            <option>CPCtrl</option>
                            <option>DesiHW</option>
                            <option>DigScroll</option>
                            <option>DFGas</option>
                            <option>DWall</option>
                            <option>MZ-DD</option>
                            <option>DPP</option>
                            <option>Encl</option>
                            <option>PlateHX</option>
                            <option>ERW</option>
                            <option>ERWModule</option>
                            <option>ERVMod</option>
                            <option>EvapBP</option>
                            <option>PreEvap</option>
                            <option>XP</option>
                            <option>Extend</option>
                            <option>FanWall</option>
                            <option>FillStat</option>
                            <option>FFilt</option>
                            <option>PFilt</option>
                            <option>CarbFilt</option>
                            <option>CustFilt</option>
                            <option>MGH(H)</option>
                            <option>GHeat</option>
                            <option>HighStatic</option>
                            <option>HGBP</option>
                            <option>HGRH</option>
                            <option>HPConv</option>
                            <option>GFHumid</option>
                            <option>TOHumid</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>

                </tr>


</table>
```

Comment: That works as it should Thank you. Only one question, Is there a way to make it so the number is 2 digits. So it would be xxxxT-01 and than the next row would be 02 and so on?

Comment: Found a small issue with this. If the user adds to many rows and clicks delete, the last row is deleted as it should be. The issue is if the user clicks the delete button lets say one to many times the Add button no longer works. In a nut shell once the delete button is pressed the Add button no longer functions.